# Add Dynamic Action(Javascript Event) to the first checkbox (Oracle Apex)

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to ask for help with regards to working with the checkbox item in oracle apex. My problem is that I cannot add a javascript event or dynamic action to the first checkbox for the purpose of toggling a check all event.

I have tried accessing the auto-generated id ex. P100_SAMPLE_CHECKBOX_0 and put it on jquery selector in dynamic action property but somehow still does not work.

Goal: Using jquery / javascript code to toggle check all when the first checkbox is clicked.

Further Explanation:
[image] 
 
So as you can see on the top image I have a checkbox item which composed of year from 2016 to 2020. So let's assume that there was already an "All" checkbox on top of 2016. So what I wanted to do is upon clicking the first checkbox (which is "All") all the checkbox from 2016 up to the end will automatically be checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take note of the DA scope, it should be dynamic, otherwise partial page refreshes will stop your DA from working as expected.

There is also a `:first` selector, which will deliver the first component within a set.

Today I also modified the header of a column in a report to select/select all items, and controlled it that way.

Comment: I have tried to set the :first selector value under the property click event of checkbox item but still does not fire what was inside of the true statement. By the way I was currently using the checkbox item alone and not the report one

I also tried to utilize the .append() jquery function on page load but still it does not allow me to append something using DA

Comment: Checkboxes have a few web components pulled together, it took me some time to get it right. It's hard to dissect what you're attempting without seeing syntax examples.